# routing for vlan

Tags: router, vlan, esx

I'm trying to setup a virtual interface on a 20.04 instance that can route to the internet.

vlan 66 is working and is accessible by other devices that are strictly on that vlan. VLAN 66's Gateway is 192.168.66.1 (pfsense) and is a /24 network.

This adds a proper vlan 66 (192.168.66.3) to the VM.  However I cannot ping this device from any other vlan 66 device. Do I have the routing incorrect?

Netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.2,1.1.1.1]
    ens66: {}

  vlans:
    vlan.66:
      id: 66
      link: ens160
      addresses: [192.168.66.3/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.1.1
          metric: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

this configuration contains 2 default routes. But you see only one in your  routing table

```
ip route
```

In your case it is even worse  the gateway used in the vlan.66 route is not part of the local vlan.66 network. This will never work.

Options:

1. Remove the second default route and use more specific network routes

Off the Record:
Replace

```
gateway4: 192.168.1.1
```

By

```
routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: I did remove the 2nd gateway but still can't ping the 66.1 gateway.  Since the switch that ESX is hanging off of can ping that gateway I'm down to thinking that ESX is blocking the traffic somehow as it's unaware of the VLAN?

Comment: try to ping the `192.168.66.1` and check the arp cache afterwards `arp -an`. If you find an entry for `192.168.66.1` there is a firewall issue, if not your network setup in ESX is incorrect.

Comment: 66.254 (switch - trunk port is set) where the esx is plugged in shows as incomplete ... but the switch can ping the firewall.  Looks like the ESX.